# Terraform - AWS - How to prevent EBS volumes from being deleted?

Tags: amazon-web-services, volume, terraform, terminate, amazon-ebs

I'm fairly new to Terraform so I'm hoping the issue is something I'm doing wrong.

I have some instances which need separate EBS volumes attached. These are defined as three separate Terraform resources:

```
aws_instance
aws_ebs_volume
aws_volume_attachment
```

When the instances boot, within AWS console the volumes say they have 'Delete on termination' protection, yet Terraform still destroys them:

[image: aws ebs volume screenshot]

If you use the 'block_device' mapping within the aws_instance resource definition you can prevent it from being terminated:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#delete_on_termination-1

But this does option not appear in the ebs_volume resource:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/ebs_volume.html

How do I stop Terraform from deleting my EBS volumes?

I tried doing this, but it just stops the terraform destroy job from running:

```
  lifecycle = {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show your `terraform plan ...` output.

Comment: Hi - do you want the plan from the create or the destroy or both?

Irrespective, they are quite large outputs and contains lots of business data (tags, names identifiers) so I'm trying to redact all the business identifiable data from it. Please bear with me. Thanks

If you only want specific sections let me know.

Comment: Please show aws_instance destroying plan output.

Comment: Here you go -> https://pastebin.com/4B9nf4Bq 
Thanks

Comment: Did you put the `lifecycle` meta-parameter into the `aws_ebs_volume` resource block?

Comment: @KJH - yes in the volume block.

Answer (score 1):

It is doing exactly what the documentation says it will do, so Terraform will not allow a `terraform destroy`, if you need it to do this then I suggest moving these resources to their own terraform directory away from other resources.

> prevent_destroy (bool) - This flag provides extra protection against
>   the destruction of a given resource. When this is set to true, any
>   plan that includes a destroy of this resource **will return an error
>   message.**

Answer (score 0):

In general, `terraform destroy` will destroy all resources. If you would rather destroy only specific resources, you can use for example: `terraform destroy -target=aws_instance.some_name`

For your EBS volume example, you would also have to destroy the `aws_volume_attachment` resource.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to prevent your ec2 instance for accidental deletion, you can use the below command on your create ec2 instance resource section,

**disable_api_termination= "true"**

I have verified couple of time it's working fine.

Happy learning....!!

Comment: You could improve this answer by linking to documentation. Furthermore, my quick research indicates, that there are open bugs in Terraform, which can lead to this parameter not working as expected -- something that should probably be addressed as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best thing to do is to hardcode the volume id in the attachment like this:

```
resource "aws_volume_attachment" "etc-attachment" {
  volume_id = "vol-0fc0c123261262855"
  instance_id = aws_instance.main.id
  force_detach = true
  device_name = "/dev/sdc"
}
```

and don't include a `resource "aws_ebs_volume" ".." {..}`.

That way, whenever you use `terraform destroy`, the volume won't be destroyed.